# sql or pl/sql to return multiple counts for every minute of the day

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table that contains an id column and three date columns.

For example, I currently run the following: (this is a very simple example with no where clause)

```
select count(*), trunc(t.date1,'MI')
from schema.table t
group by trunc(t.date1,'MI')
order by 2;
```

I do the same for t.date2 and t.date3 and combine the results in excel.

I am looking for one sql query or anonymous plsql block which, will return every minute of the day and the count of each date column.

Sample output for request:

```
sysdate by minute       count date1    count date2     count date3
1/18/2016 00:00         4              2               12
1/18/2016 00:01         3              10              7
etc..
```

I appreciate any help and direction the community provides.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `union all`:

```
select bymin, sum(cnt1) as cnt1, sum(cnt2) as cnt2, sum(cnt3) as cnt3
from ((select trunc(t.date1, 'MI') as bymin, count(*) as cnt1, 0 as cnt2, 0 as cnt3
       from schema.table t
       group by trunc(t.date1, 'MI')
      ) union all
      (select trunc(t.date2, 'MI') as bymin, 0, count(*) as cnt2, 0
       from schema.table t
       group by trunc(t.date2, 'MI')
      ) union all
      (select trunc(t.date3, 'MI') as bymin, 0, 0 count(*) as cnt3
       from schema.table t
       group by trunc(t.date3, 'MI')
      )
     ) t
group by bymin;
```

Another alternative is to use `full outer join`.  However, that involves lots of `coalesce()`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to unpivot the columns and then do a conditional group by, eg:

```
with mins as (select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/1440 dt
              from   dual
              connect by level <= 1440),
      t1 as (select case when d.lvl = 1 then 'date1'
                         when d.lvl = 2 then 'date2'
                         when d.lvl = 3 then 'date3'
                    end dt_type,
                    case when d.lvl = 1 then trunc(dt1, 'mi')
                         when d.lvl = 2 then trunc(dt2, 'mi')
                         when d.lvl = 3 then trunc(dt3, 'mi')
                    end dt
             from   tablename t
                    cross join (select 0 + level lvl from dual connect by level <= 3) d)
select mins.dt,
       count(case when t1.dt_type = 'date1' then t1.dt end) count_dt1,
       count(case when t1.dt_type = 'date2' then t1.dt end) count_dt2,
       count(case when t1.dt_type = 'date3' then t1.dt end) count_dt3
from   mins
       left join t1 on (mins.dt = t1.dt)
group by mins.dt
order by mins.dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example. I hope it will help you. Of course it is better to select rows from schema.table only for that date in order to improve performance.

```
WITH minutes AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
        '2016-01-01 00:00'::TIMESTAMP,
        '2016-01-01 23:59'::TIMESTAMP,
        '1 MINUTE'
    ) AS minute
)
SELECT
    a.minute,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date1 >= a.minute AND b.date1 < a.minute + INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date2 >= a.minute AND b.date2 < a.minute + INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.date3 >= a.minute AND b.date3 < a.minute + INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1
FROM minutes a
LEFT JOIN schema.table b ON (TRUE)
GROUP BY a.minute
ORDER BY a.minute ASC
```